# PhoneGap/cordova + Ionic framework + Yahoo Id + WebAPI + OAuthWebSecurity

Tags: cordova, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth, phonegap-plugins, yahoo-oauth

I'm struggling with enabling logging to my mobile app via Yahoo Id.
There is one working web application that uses OAuthWebSecurity and enables logging via facebook, gmail, windows, twitter, yahoo. My task is to create mobile application with some of web application's functionality.

Web application:

- MVC4
- OAuthWebSecurity
- WebApi controllers created for mobile application for verification logged in user and then getting data from our DB

Mobile application:

- Ionic build on cordova
- for OAuth I'm using OAuth nq-cordova plugin (doesn't provide logic for yahoo provider so I created my own based on existing methods)
- angular.js $http service for querying provider's endpoints (if needed)

Designed (not by me) authentication flow in my mobile app is:

mobile login screen -> choosen provider login window -> authentication -> redirect back with OAuth access_token and/or user_id -> query our WebApi to verify user identity -> get data from DB

After querying Yahoo authetication endpoint:
https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?client_id=' + clientId + '&redirect_uri=' + redirectUri' + '&response_type=token

The response is:
{
access_token: 'my token in here'
token_type: bearer,
xoauth_yahoo_guid: 'my guid in here'
}

In my WebApi user verification method uses OAuthWebSecurity:

```
(OAuthWebSecurity.Login(provider, providerUserId, createPersistentCookie: false)
```

I tried to pass as 'providerUserId' value from xoauth_yahoo_guid (the yahoo's authentication endopint's response field), but it doesn't work.

While debugging web application I noticed that for the same yahoo account method
 `var result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication()` returns Yahoo openId in property `result.ProviderUserId`.

Can anyone advice me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for your time.